# Select rRadio Button by default angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button, radio-group, checked

I am using Angular Material. I have a `mat-radio-group` and a `mat-radio-button` I want to select by default a radio button object option but I don't understand why it doesn't select by default.

Here is my code.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatRadioChange } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { StudentService } from '../core/services/students.service';


export interface Student{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  course: string;
  avegareMarks: number;
}

export interface Students{
    students: Student[];
    bestStudent: Student;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  

  studentSelected!: Student;
  students!: Students;
 
  constructor(private studentsService: StudentsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudents();
  }

  
  private getStudents(){
    this.studentsService.findAll().subscribe((data:Students) =>  {
      this.students = data.students;
      this.studentSelected = data.bestStudent;
    }) 
  }

  compareFn(c1: Student): boolean {
    return c1 && this.studentSelected && c1.id === this.studentSelected.id && c1.name === this.studentSelected.name && 
    c1.avegareMarks === this.studentSelected.avegareMarks && c1.course === this.studentSelected.course;
  }
 

}
```

Here is my template:

```
  <div style="margin: 20px">
        <mat-card style="max-width: 450px;">
            <mat-card-subtitle>Students</mat-card-subtitle>
            <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" class="example-radio-group"
                [(ngModel)]="studentSelected">
                <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button"
                    *ngFor="let student of students" [value]="student" [checked]="compareFn(student)>
                    {{ student | json }}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `studentSelected` has to be one from `this.students` so that the reference matches one of the options. Get rid of `[checked]` and `compareFn`, as you don't need that if you do this:

```
this.studentSelected = data.bestStudent 
    ? data.students.find(s => s.id === data.bestStudent.id) 
    : null;
```